# change space between horizontal (grid) lines for line chart

Tags: charts, chart.js

is it possible to manually change space between horizontal (grid) lines? setting `maintainAspectRatio: false,`kinda does the trick but makes the graph height too narrow. I see that there is an option to extend existing chart types

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
// Passing in a name registers this chart in the Chart namespace in the same way
name: "LineAlt",
initialize: function(data){
    console.log('My Line chart extension');
    Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
}
});

// Creates a line chart in the same way
new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(data);
```

but I dont know how to catch and change height between lines. I am new to chartjs so can it be done? any help would be much appreciated. I am trying to change height of the graph or set max-height so it does not look too big when it's responsive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in options. While there is no option to directly set the horizontal spacing between grid lines, you can use the below (from http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration)

```
// Creates a line chart in the same way
new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(data, {
     scaleOverride: true,

     scaleSteps: 10,
     scaleStepWidth: 20,
     scaleStartValue: 0,       
});
```

Note that you need all 4 settings.

Adjust the scaleStepWidth to control the spacing.

Comment: although your code reduces the space between the grid lines it does not change the height of the graph which I was hoping to achieve with it :( I would like to set max-height for the graph or calculate new height somehow as the graph looks too big, while keeping it responsive!? setting `maintainAspectRatio: false` on the other hand makes the graph height too narrow?

Comment: when responsive is set the graph will resize to fit the container (if maintainAspectRatio is false), so all you have to do is set a height for the container. If that doesn't work - could you set up a fiddle?

Comment: and I was trying to calculate and change graph height :(( thanks

Comment: @potatopeelings is it possible to change the distance between the x-axis points?? like distance between the horizontal grids or the labels?